# Question about UITabBar Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

Hello Im completely new to iPhone sdk.
Im trying to build an app that shows a welcome screen for 3seconds then it switches to the main app screen which has a tab bar view.
My welcome screen is working fine when tested in isolation. But after configuring the UITabBarController in the main.xib the welcome screen is not shown. Though Tab Bar works properly.

The controller for welcome screen I've named as rootController.
In AppDeligate I've the following code -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    //  Override point for customization after application launch.    

    RootController* rootController = [[RootController alloc] init];
    //  [self.window insertSubview:rootController.view atIndex:4];
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

After the welcome screen is shown I'll remove its view and I expect the main view consisting of tab bar to be shown. What could be the possible error?

Comment: sry its MainWindow.xib not main.xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem very neatly. I used `presentModalViewController:animated:` and dismissed in `timerDidRan:` method. Though I subclassed `UIViewController` and not `UITabBarcontroller` which I feel is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the view of the tab bar controller is loaded after applicationDidFinishLaunching... method returns, so it will be added to your application window AFTER you added the view of RootController, which is now beneath the tab bar view.

There could be multiple ways to achieve what you want, but I would present the welcome view modally, in viewDidLoad method in the tab bar controller. Although you need to subclass The tab bar view controller class for this, the code will be the easiest to understand.

Subclass UITabBarController, use it in the nib file,and override viewDidLoad and do something like

[super viewDidLoad];
//make a RootController object
[ self presentModalViewController:welcomeViewController animated:NO];

You will dismiss the modal view when you want.

Comment: Apple doesn't encourage subclassing UITabBarController. The problem is that the RootController nib is loaded and then the main nib is loaded but I've used timer which runs after 3secs in RootController. Before this timer runs the main nib is loaded and the root Controller nib goes behind the scenes. Thinking Still how to solve it in a neat way.

Comment: Apple means not to try modifying behaviors of UITabBarController. I don't see a problem subclassing UITabBarController just to add a modal view when it's loaded at all, while I see a lot of problems in using a timer to delay the nib loading. The RootController nib is called in loadView method because the main nib requests the root controller view to appear and it is expected when viewDidLoad is called, all nib objects are properly loaded. Never delay nib loading like that.

Comment: Well, if you really hate to subclass UITabBarController, you may have another view controller the view of which always exists, having the tab bar controller view as a subview, and in its viewDidLoad you can present welcome screen modally. But there is no point at all. I would definitely just subclass UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: add both the welcome view controller and the tabbar controller to your mainwindow.xib, create outlets for them and link them up.

Then just show them both:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window addSubview:welcomeViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In your welcomeViewController you can then set its view to hidden after 3 seconds, remove itself from the window, etc.